# Что такое "экономия средств языка"?

Tags: языкознание

Почитала обсуждение о "сто грамм(ов)", и там встретился такой термин как "экономия средств языка", то есть, укорачивание слов.
Но объясните мне, зачем? Я еще понимаю, когда укорачивают слова в письменной речи — грубо говоря, чтобы меньше кнопочек нажимать или меньше букв писать. Но в устной-то?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Да как-то так само происходит, без указующего перста. Короче хочется сказать, побыстрее, попроще. 
Примером экономии языковых средств может служить метонимия. Мы говорим:прочитал Толстого, а не роман Толстого. Съел три тарелки - без уточнения чего именно, ведь из ситуации и так понятно. Или на вопрос "что-то с тобой?" отвечаем просто "Давление". Вместо:"У меня повышенное давление.

Answer (score 2):

Это так. Но грамматика от этого страдать не должна. Не надо для экономии "апельсинов" сокращать до "апельсин" т.п.

Comment: Да никто целенаправленно не вредит грамматике. Просто есть "груш", "яблок", почему бы не быть "апельсин". Кроме закона экономии есть еще закон аналогии.